# App crashes when setting layout background

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to set a drawable resource as background for my main relative layout via java, but whenever I do it, my app crashes.

Here is the part of the code which doesn't work fine:

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {

    RelativeLayout layout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.layout.activity_game);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
        layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image);

    }

}
```

Any idea?
Thanks in advance

Comment: can u post the stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember,you are trying to find a view by id but what you are doing is actually trying to inflate a layout the wrong way.Change the `R.layout.activity_game` to R.id.activity_game and make sure the relative layout is givent the

```
android:id = "@+id/activity_game"
```

The full code should be

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {

RelativeLayout layout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
    layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_game);
    layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image);
}
```

}
Hope it helps.Happy coding.

Answer (score 3):

Call `findViewById()` only after `setContentView()` and supply an identifier in `R.id` (and not `R.layout`) so that it can return something other than `null`.

Comment: Yep, good idea, and it had to be part of the problem, but doesn't work, keeps on crashing